# Создание фильтра для проверки текущего пользователя

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь сделать проверку на то что бы по адресу /controler/user1/action  был доступ только у user1, у остальных ошибка.

Задан такой маршрут url: "controler/{username}/{action}/{id}". 
я могу конечно прописать проверку в каждом действие, вот так:

```
        public ActionResult Index(string username)
{
var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
var Name = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "UserName").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

if (username == name)

//----//
            return View();
}
```

но действий много, код постоянно будет повторяться, и подумал что можно реализовать данное через фильтры. Но как получить в фильтрах имя пользователя из url?

это не работает почему то:

```
string UserName = RouteData.Values["username"].ToString();
```

и так тоже не сработало:

```
if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Segments.Contains(UserName))
```

Если делать поиск строки в Url то может возникнуть ситуация когда например в url будет идентичное слово (вывод в url названия статьи к примеру), а это не безопасно, кто угодно может получить доступ к чужим записям.
Можете подсказать как вытащить нужное значение из урла? и верно ли я вообще делаю?

Comment: > код постоянно будет повторяться

А почему это проблема? Вынесите проверяющий код в отдельную процедуру.

Comment: @VladD подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: @Колямбий: Эээ... Вы не знаете, как написать функцию?

    void EnsureUser(string username)
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        var name = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "UserName")
                           .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

        if (username != name)
            throw new WhateverIsAppropriateException("No access for user " + name);
    }

Comment: @VladD спасибо. меня заклинило =)
а для WhateverIsAppropriateException что нужно подключить? а то не нашел в гугле

Comment: @Колямбий: Ну, название я выдумал, бросьте тот тип исключения, который вы считаете правильным в этой ситуации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а чем Вам не подходит атрибут на контроллер:
[Authorize (Users="user1")] и к данному контроллеру или методу (смотря где расположите) будет иметь доступ только user1

Comment: если же Вам понадобится более сложная проверка для доступа то всегда можно написать свой фильтр, более подробно можно почитать [здесь](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/8.1.php)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы советовал использовать не фильтр, а IRouteConstraint на маршрут, в котором была бы логика проверки этого username (выполняется на этапе подбора маршрута)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?